# Animation for two elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an animation which triggers when I put my cursor over a link. I would like to animate the link, but also the background.

You can see what I've tried in the code below, but I don't understand why it doesn't work?
I can give some example of the links if required.

Can someone help me?

```css
.listhead7,
.listhead7:visited {
  background-color: white;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 689px;
  position: fixed;
}

.listhead,
.listhead2,
.listhead3,
.listhead4,
.listhead5,
.listhead6 {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}

.listhead:visited,
.listhead2:visited,
.listhead3:visited,
.listhead4:visited,
.listhead5:visited,
.listhead6:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(245, 244, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}

.listhead:hover,
.listhead2:hover,
.listhead3:hover,
.listhead4:hover,
.listhead5:hover,
.listhead6:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead2:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead3:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead4:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead5:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.listhead6:hover~.listhead7 {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="listhead7">Nothing</div>
<a href="#class1" class="listhead">Machine settings</a><a href="#class2" class="listhead2">Amplificator transformation</a><a href="#class3" class="listhead3">Shapes dimensions of sonotrode</a> <a href="#class4" class="listhead4">Material of sonotrode</a>
<a
  href="#class5" class="listhead5">Amplitude regulation</a><a href="#class6" class="listhead6">Result</a>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: Yes mmirbekian its excactly what I want

Comment: Nah, a guy told me that he will test with style="" in the div you think it can works ? He is answering me wait a minute

Comment: I'm trying to make the bakground doing the animation too when I put my cursor over the link. Here is the new code of the bcakground :
```
.listhead7, .listhead7:visited {
    background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    top: 6px;
    right: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    bottom: 687px;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please test the answer below  to see if that's what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the background does the animation as well

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    .listhead7 {
      margin: 50px;
    }
    
    .listhead7,
    .listhead7:visited {
      background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
      top: 6px;
      right: 6px;
      left: 6px;
      bottom: 687px;
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 10px;
      opacity: 90%;
    }
    
    .listhead,
    .listhead2,
    .listhead3,
    .listhead4,
    .listhead5,
    .listhead6 {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: rgb(245, 244, 255);
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    }
    
    .listhead:visited,
    .listhead2:visited,
    .listhead3:visited,
    .listhead4:visited,
    .listhead5:visited,
    .listhead6:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: rgb(245, 244, 255);
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    }
    /*.listhead7:hover{
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}*/
    
    .listhead:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .listhead2:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .listhead3:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .listhead4:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .listhead5:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .listhead6:hover {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="listhead7">
    <a href="#class1" class="listhead">Machine settings</a><a href="#class2" class="listhead2">Amplificator transformation</a><a href="#class3" class="listhead3">Shapes dimensions of sonotrode</a> <a href="#class4" class="listhead4">Material of sonotrode</a>
    <a href="#class5" class="listhead5">Amplitude regulation</a><a href="#class6" class="listhead6">Result</a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes but when I go on a lnik they all grow. I just want that the background (listhead7) and the selectionned link grow

Comment: I just edited my answer. like that?